# How to order div by class name in for loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm new to Javascript and I made several square boxes with a div and dots(svg) on top of them,

and I would like to number these divs by div id in a for loop by making an array.

How should I fix my code?

```js
    //Javascript
    //create a 12 dotBoxes spread evenly across the window
    function getGridAreaSize(){
     $('#grid-area').width($(window).width() * .5);
    }

    function getBoxSize(){
     var boxWidth = $('#grid-area').width() / 5;
     return boxWidth;
    };

    function createBoxes(){
     for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      // divsToAppend += '<div id="div' + (++i) + '" />';
            // arrayDiv[i] = document.createElement('div');
            // arrayDiv[i].id = 'dot' + i;
       // arrayDiv[i].className = 'dotBox';
       //             document.getElementById('#grid').appendChild(arrayDiv[i].id);
        // document.getElementById(arrayDiv[i].id).appendChild(dotarea);
        // document.getElementById('#dotarea').appendChild(dot);
  $('#grid').append("<div class='dotBox'><div class='dotarea'><div class='dot'></div></div></div>");
  $('.dotBox').css('width',getBoxSize());
  $('.dotBox').css('height',getBoxSize());
 };
    };

    getGridAreaSize();
    getBoxSize();
    createBoxes();
```

```html
    

    //html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <!--FONTS-->
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

     <!--STYLESHEETS-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" type="text/css" />

     <!--SCRIPTS-->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.js">    </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js">    </script>-->
    </head>

    <body>
 <svg id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="line original" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0" />
 </svg>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="splash">
   <h1>Hello! My name is Soheum Hwang</h1>
   <h2>Hover over each dot to see my work!</h2>
   <br>
   <p id="mobile-warning"> Sorry - this kind of functionality sucks on mobile! Please view it on a desktop for best results. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="grid-area">

  <div id="grid">
   <div id="popup">
    <p>some text here</p>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="scripts/dots.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to have different texts hover on top of different boxes, so I tried to make an array of them which doesn't work..

Comment: append i too 
        $('#grid').append("<div class='dotBox' id='box_"+i+"'><div class='dotarea'><div class='dot'></div></div></div>");

Answer (score 0):

append i too while appending it to div i.e

```
$('#grid').append("<div class='dotBox' id='box_"+i+"'><div class='dotarea'><div class='dot'></div></div></div>");
```

Comment: I kept on appending i in div class ='box' but I guess I should add it at div class='dotBox'

Comment: yes, @SoHeumHwang it's up to you where you need to append i. and mark it correct if it helped you :)